# MySQL: load on startup / load each time needed

Tags: java, mysql, discord

My discord bot communicates with an external mysql server to get specific userdata, and I would like to know what of the following 2 options would be more efficient:

- **1:** Request data from the server each time a command/code is exectuted
- **2:** Load at the startup the whole table into a list and when the command/code is exectuted get the userdata from there

How much cpu would it take if I chose option 2?

Opinions are appreciated!

*Note: My bot currently is on about 22 Servers with 12000 Members*

**Edit:** the code the bot uses to communicate is [here](https://github.com/strukteon/MagnetBot/blob/master/src/main/java/utils/UserSQL.java)

Comment: Where is the Java and MySQL code?

Comment: If userdata might be refreshed, then load each time or cache for 10/5/1 mins/secs.

Comment: How often does the data  change? I ask about the data stored in the MySQL server. Observation: caching is a difficult problem in computer science. By preloading the data, you are caching it, and taking on the difficulty of managing those caches. So don't preload unless you must because of performance reasons.. Look up the acronym YAGNI and take it seriously.

Comment: @O.Jones The data changes each time a user manually updates it. All changes are made by the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use your first idea

Because if you load a big table at startup you are going to waste a lot of memory and you will not have the latest state of the DB in your list.

Also, Mysql will handle well with one request by command/code.

Comment: The only problem is that each request takes about 5 seconds to complete, and the user experience suffers from that

Comment: How did you code your dicordbot ? And does your databases really big ? Thousands ? Millions of tuples ?